# Are there parts of a ship that are hand crafted although they could be replicated?

Tags: star-trek, federation, replicator

Humans have a tendency to give value to non-essential parts of an object for sentimental reasons. While rewatching Star Trek:TNG S3E2, The Ensigns of Command, when Picard walks over to the plaque, I started to wonder if there are parts of a starship like the Enterprise that are deliberately crafted by hand and not replicated for sentimental reasons although there is no technical reason for it.

E.g. above mentioned plaque. There is no technical necessity for it but humans tend to give this plaque a high sentimental value and I could imagine that it is part of a "ceremony" to install such a plaque when a ship is put into service and that it is hand crafted.

So, are there parts of a star ship that are deliberately hand crafted although a production via replication is technically possible?

Comment: Entirely speculation, but probably the conference table.

Comment: The wooden handrail on the Enterprise D bridge where the security/tactical station is

Comment: I think you have a good question.   However it is dangerously close to "are ships replicated?"  The answer to that is very little.  In general you should assume that replicators are a convenience  that is very energy intensive.   If a table, for example, can be conventionally built - I think they would.  Would it be from 500 year old oaks built by an Amish community is a different sort of luxury question - which may be spiritually closer to what you want.